# How to get current theme of monaco-editor

Tags: monaco-editor

Is there any method to get the current theme of monaco-editor?
In monaco-editor api doc，I only find methods to set theme, for example, `setTheme` and `defineTheme`，but no `getTheme`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reference to the editor, you can use `editor._themeService._theme`

If you paste the following code into the [Monaco Playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html), open the developer tools console and run it you will see the theme name being logged out:

```
// Theme matching (i.e. applying a style to a token) happens in JavaScript.
// We must therefore register the theme rules in JavaScript.

// A custom theme must name its base theme (i.e. 'vs', 'vs-dark' or 'hc-black')
// It can then choose to inherit the rules from the base theme or not
// A rule token matching is prefix based: e.g.
//  - string will match a token with type: string, string.double.js or string.html
//  - string.double will match a token with type string.double but will not match string or string.html

// !!! Tokens can be inspected using F1 > Developer: Inspect Tokens !!!

monaco.editor.defineTheme('myCustomTheme', {
    base: 'vs', // can also be vs-dark or hc-black
    inherit: true, // can also be false to completely replace the builtin rules
    rules: [
        { token: 'comment', foreground: 'ffa500', fontStyle: 'italic underline' },
        { token: 'comment.js', foreground: '008800', fontStyle: 'bold' },
        { token: 'comment.css', foreground: '0000ff' } // will inherit fontStyle from `comment` above
    ],
    colors: {
        'editor.foreground': '#000000'
    }
});

var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
    value: getCode(),
    language: 'text/html',
    theme: 'myCustomTheme'
});

function getCode() {
    return (
        '<html><!-- // !!! Tokens can be inspected using F1 > Developer: Inspect Tokens !!! -->\n<head>\n   <!-- HTML comment -->\n <style type="text/css">\n       /* CSS comment */\n </style>\n  <script type="javascript">\n        // JavaScript comment\n </' +
        'script>\n</head>\n<body></body>\n</html>'
    );
}

console.log(editor._themeService._theme)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative: `editor._themeService.getColorTheme()`